# Python doesn't detect a colliderect for one of my objects

Tags: python, pygame, rectangles

I have this code

```
if ball.colliderect(border_up_rect):
    border_up_collide = True
elif ball.colliderect(border_down_rect):
    border_down_collide = True
elif ball.colliderect(goal_attack_rect):
    my_score += 1
elif ball.colliderect(goal_def_rect):
    ai_score += 1


if border_up_collide == True:
    if where_did_it_come_from == True:
        ball_x -= 7
        ball_y += 2
        pboard_shoot1 = False
        pboard_shoot2 = False
        pboard_shoot3 = False
    elif where_did_it_come_from == False:
        ball_x -= 3
        ball_y += 2
        ai_shoot1 = False
        ai_shoot2 = False
        ai_shoot3 = False
elif border_down_collide == True:
    if where_did_it_come_from == True:
        ball_x -= 7
        ball_y -= 2
        pboard_shoot1 = False
        pboard_shoot2 = False
        pboard_shoot3 = False
    elif where_did_it_come_from == False:
        ball_x -= 3
        ball_y -= 2
        ai_shoot1 = False
        ai_shoot2 = False
        ai_shoot3 = False
elif goal_attack_collide == True:
    if where_did_it_come_from == True:
        ball_x = 600
        ball_y = 220
        pboard_shoot1 = False
        pboard_shoot2 = False
        pboard_shoot3 = False
    elif where_did_it_come_from == False:
        ball_x = 600
        ball_y = 220
        ai_shoot1 = False
        ai_shoot2 = False
        ai_shoot3 = False
```

Here it works fine with `border_up_rect` and also every other `collide.rect`, but it doesn't work with `border_down_rect`. It just lets the ball go through it.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `border_down_rect` isn't functioning is because `border_up_rect` is still true and until `border_up_rect` is true it won't toggle the `elif` statement.